# Loopback.js - Upsert/updateOrCreate() 500 error

Tags: loopbackjs

Help with this would be greatly appreciated!

I recently updated `Loopback` and now get 500 errors when trying to update a record using the `upsert()` method otherwise know as `updateOrCreate()`. 
I'm not a `Loopback` expert but from what i can gather it seems to be an issue with the `validateUpsert` model definition option.

For example. When called on the Users model it will return a 500 error if this is false and any required properties for the model are missing from the parameters . If set as true it returns a 422 as expected as the model is validated for the missing properties.

Current Loopback modules:

```
"loopback": "^2.8.0",
"loopback-boot": "^2.4.0",
"loopback-connector": "^2.4.0",
"loopback-connector-mysql": "^2.3.0",
"loopback-connector-rest": "^2.0.0",
"loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.7.0",
```

Thanks
Jason

Comment: What is stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. My stacktrace can be seen here in this pastebin http://pastebin.ca/3666998

Comment: Please post the call to upsert. Looking at the pastebin, you are simply not passing proper properties to the upsert function